# Print some pages colour, others grayscale

Tags: scribus

I'm creating a booklet where only the first and the last page are allowed to be colour and the rest grayscale (for printing; CMYK). How do I do this with Scribus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make separated files. One for the interiors and other for the covers.

The interiors should be nor printed as CMYK, but grayscale only.

An aditional tip:
Depending on the pint system and the number of total booklets printed there is a chance you can actually have the interiors of the cover pages in full color too at the same price. Ask the printer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But how do I amalgamate the two? Can I send two PDFs?

Comment: You can send two if you can talk with a printhouse person (a technical one). Small printhouses usually can do some discussions without the tax ticking. Several PDFs can be combined in Adobe Acrobat (=the industry standard). There are low cost alternatives such as Foxit Fantom.  Even online PDF processing services are available, also free ones. CMYK and BW pages must be in a strictly defined order, if you want to gain some savings by having BW pages. Consult with the printhouse.

Comment: I have seen online print-shops which even request separate files, if you tick that the book inside-pages are to be black only (grayscale). In Europe, it seems that covers almost "must" be in colour.

So before you spend a lot of time amalgamating, check with your preferred printer.

Comment: Of course an online printer will sell you the full package. But I have being doing 1-8 ink projects for quite some years now, and the final price is diferent. And this also works for publications made in a copy shop project.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of alternatives I investigated:

- As proposed by Rafael, export the cover and interior separately (one with Output Intended For -> Grayscale, one with Output Intended For -> Printer in the Color tab of the export dialog). If the printer requires it, concatenate them back, e.g. with the command-line tool pdftk:

  `pdftk A=cover.pdf B=interior.pdf cat A1-2 B A3-4 output result.pdf`

  (PDF compatibility etc. should be preserved, I hope)
- Set up the interior as grayscale to begin with. In particular, add the Scribus image effect Grayscale to all images inside. Caveat: If you export your PDF to CMYK (Scribus color management enabled, e.g. PDF/X-1a), this Grayscale image effect will lead to much darker images in the resulting PDF due to a long standing bug/feature in Scribus (https://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=4270). Thus, probably not a good alternative right now, unless you choose to embed RGB images with profiles instead (e.g. PDF/X-3).
- Convert images to grayscale outside of Scribus. This even works nicely if you want to have both a colored version (e.g. for digital publishing) and a greyscale version of your PDF:

  1. Setup your document with color images, with all images/resources sourced from a subfolder next to your sla file (best practice anyways). Export the colored version as usual.
  2. When you're done, copy your sla file and all resources to another place (e.g. another subfolder).
  3. Batch-convert all images that should be grayscale with a tool of your choice, e.g. ImageMagick (Caution: overwrites images!):

     `mogrify -set colorspace Gray -separate -average images/*`
  4. If you open the copied sla file, Scribus will read the now grayscale images, since it uses relative paths.